# Emulate console by sending data on one UDP port, and receive text from another

Tags: console, socket, udp, socat

*Note: I also posted [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/824975/104806), because I'm not sure where it belongs*

I'm trying to establish a "console-like" connection with a [National Instruments cRIO-FRC.](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-19103)

It broadcasts its console output onto `255.255.255.255`, UDP port `6666`. I can listen to it with:

```
$ socat UDP-RECV:6666,broadcast,reuseaddr -
```

It listens to commands on its IP address, UDP port  `6668`. I can send commands with:

```
$ socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:10.8.54.2:6668,broadcast,reuslsddr
```

However, these 2 commands run in separate terminals. I.e. I have to type into one, and view results in another window. Is there a way to concurrently run these two programs, or is there a more appropriate program to use other than `socat`?

Comment: Cross posting is a [reason for closing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) your question on this site. If you want to keep it here, delete the question on SU, update your question here and announce that it was closed there.

Comment: Where do you think is more appropriate for this?

Comment: I have almost zero knowledge about what is going on on SU, the subject doesn't seem to be of topic here or there, but that doesn't say much about if/when you get an answer. There are also some people active here and on SU

Comment: It's slightly more on-topic here than on SU. I'd close the SU one.

Comment: Sorry, that likely won't work just like that, but `man socat` says: `-u: unidirectional mode: first address is only used for reading, and the second address is only used for writing...` Probably that's what you want, so you can also read and write to the terminal you're looking at as well.

Comment: I've read into `-u` before, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it

Comment: I'm looking at `man` now and I don't believe it's right exactly - or it is and also needs `bind:` or `EXEC:` or something. There's just so *much* you can do with `socat` that I've always been too daunted to learn it very well... But I *think* you need to bind 6666 to 6668 or something.... There is also the bi-directional `!!` thing... You might also look at `netcat` - it can be simpler - but use the BSD package because GNU `nc` *sucks*!